# Dynamic sum of textbox values asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my application I have five textboxes. The task which I want to do is that to add(sum) the values entered in the five texboxes and display it in the 6th textbox. I have tried the following code but it is not showing the addition. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="D1" runat="server"  Width="50px" onkeypress="return validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D2" runat="server" Width="50px" onkeypress="return validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D3" runat="server" Width="50px" onkeypress="return validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D4" runat="server" Width="50px" onkeypress="return validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D5" runat="server" Width="50px" onkeypress="return validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" ></asp:TextBox>


 Total Hours<asp:TextBox ID="Total" runat="server" Width="50px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        //Function to allow only numbers to textbox

        function validate(key) {
            //getting key code of pressed key
            var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
            var phn = document.getElementById('D1');
            var phn1 = document.getElementById('D2');
            var phn2 = document.getElementById('D3');
            var phn3 = document.getElementById('D4');
            var phn4 = document.getElementById('D5');
            //comparing pressed keycodes
            if (!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        void function calc(dat) {
            var a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, total, pp;

            a1 = document.getElementById("<%=D1.ClientID%>").value;
            a2 = document.getElementById("<%=D2.ClientID%>").value;
            a3 = document.getElementById("<%=D3.ClientID%>").value;
            a4 = document.getElementById("<%=D4.ClientID%>").value;
            a5 = document.getElementById("<%=D5.ClientID%>").value;


            total = parseInt(a1) + parseInt(a2) + parseInt(a3) + parseInt(a4) + parseInt(a5);

            document.getElementById(<%=Total%>).value = total;

        }

</script>
```

Comment: you are missing quotes around `(<%=Total%>)` probably should be `("%=Total%>")` like your other getElement* calls

Comment: Use `'<%=D1.ClientID%>'.. etc` inside method `validate()` as well. Also use `'<%=Total.ClientID %>'` inside `calc()`

Comment: it gives me an error that `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'calc' is undefined`

Comment: @SPandya Add your JavaScript in the head tag

Comment: @wiz kid: didn't get you

Comment: @SPandya Move your JS code and add to the html `head` tag

Comment: @wiz kid: its already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/5UUAD/1/)

** HTML **

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="D1" runat="server"  Width="50px" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D2" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D3" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D4" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="D5" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>


 Total Hours<asp:TextBox ID="Total" runat="server" Width="50px" ReadOnly="True" ClientIDMode=static"></asp:TextBox>
```

** Jquery **

```
    $('.sum').keydown(function(e) {
        //getting key code of pressed key
        var keycode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        //comparing pressed keycodes
        if (!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $('.sum').keyup(function(e) {
        var total=0;
        var current;
        $('.sum').each(function(){
            current=parseInt($(this).val());
        if($.isNumeric(current))
        {
           total+=  current;              
        }
        });
        $("#Total").val(total);

    });
```

Comment: fiddle is working fine but not working when I try to execute with visual studio 2012

Comment: @SPandya Did you add clientidmode=static for total textbox?what happened on keyup and keydown?

Comment: yes I did. And now I can also enter the alphabetic values as well. which should not be there

Comment: @SPandya I hope you write the jquery code on document.ready function and also check in firebug Is there any jquery issue?

Comment: opps...i made a silly mistake. Forgot to add the jquery reference. Sorry.

Comment: onemore thing after this change I am not able to sum the float values and numpad is also not working

Answer (score 1):

Plz Check the Modifications:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(key) {

        //getting key code of pressed key
        var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
        var phn = document.getElementById('D1');
        var phn1 = document.getElementById('D2');
        var phn2 = document.getElementById('D3');
        var phn3 = document.getElementById('D4');
        var phn4 = document.getElementById('D5');
        //comparing pressed keycodes
        if (!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    function calc() {
        var a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, total, pp;

        a1 = document.getElementById("<%=D1.ClientID%>").value;
        a2 = document.getElementById("<%=D2.ClientID%>").value;
        a3 = document.getElementById("<%=D3.ClientID%>").value;
        a4 = document.getElementById("<%=D4.ClientID%>").value;
        a5 = document.getElementById("<%=D5.ClientID%>").value;

        total = parseInt(a1) + parseInt(a2) + parseInt(a3) + parseInt(a4) + parseInt(a5);

        if ($.isNumeric(total)) {
            $('#Total').val(total);
        }

    }

</script>
```